# I get 2 stripes when doing texture painting

Tags: texture-painting

so Im following Andrew Price course of doing a donut in Blender 3.0 and in this part: [Course Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LeTDpNrdbg&t=627s) where he does the white line in the middle:

[image: How it should look]

Bute I get this:

It looks like there is no issue when I paint anywhere on the donut, but then 2 strips start showing, if i paint over those strips it paints the whole area, there also appear 2 thin lines in the inner hole of the donut, I did everything like in the course video I tried selecting all vertices and recalculating outsides, searched on goodle, on the youtube comments but cant find a solution.

Here is a video that I made showing the issue so u could understand a little better:

[My issue video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NX8pkVyClYA)

[image]

Comment: Hello, your unwrap must be bad, or too much bleeding for your brush and not enough margin between the UVs? Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/